# How to install Lex on AIX 7.1

Tags: aix

I would like to install OpenMotif on an AIX 7.1, but it gave an error of missing lex. How can I install lex on AIX 7.1? Where can I find the package for it?

I got the following error when installing OpenMotif:

Target "includes" is up to date.

including in ./tools/wml...

lex wmllex.l

lex: not found

Comment: If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give  details and context, users around here can provide a useful answer.

Comment: Updated question will error message.

Answer (score 1):

Lex is part of the standard AIX, you just need to install the bos.adt.utils fileset from your AIX 7 installation media.

Answer (score 0):

Lex is not available from the aix-toolbox, nor bullfreeware.com. You would be far better off getting any sort of Linux box, even a PC. AIX support for opensource is half-hearted at best.